Mini split instead of central AC to save money
just purchased a 3/3 1450sf two story townhouse. We work from home in the upstairs office. We run our central AC to cool the office and the bedroom at night, but realize it’s a waste to cool the entire house just for those two small rooms. Plus our electric bill was very high last month. Is it more efficient to buy two mini splits for those rooms and not run central air?

One mini can cool two or more rooms depending on sizing.  Minis are usually better bang per cooling costs than a regular AC unit.  You do have choices, plus upstairs cooling tends to drop down below/cool air drops/hot air rises.  If the door is close, then you might get hit with hot air when open.

A definite maybe.
There are a few different factors involved.
Efficiency
Broadly speaking, newer systems are much more efficient than older systems. In the US, the efficiency is measured in SEER, and a higher number is better. Mini-splits are readily available up to 22 SEER, possibly higher (I haven't done an exhaustive search). The minimum SEER currently allowed is 14. A system that is several years old may have an even lower SEER.
Area Being Cooled
A central unit will be working to cool everything when you only need part of the building cooled. In addition, for a central unit cooling two floors to get the top floor comfortable will get the bottom floor colder - how much colder depends on the design of the building. Cooling just the areas needed will require less effort = energy = money. However, due to the humidity (in most places), you will still want some air conditioning in the rest of the building. But you might be able to set the central system so that it gets the first floor to 76 and the second floor to 80, with the mini-split doing the extra work to get the key rooms to 72.
Depending on the age of your central air conditioner, you may want to install a multi-head mini-split to actually replace your central air conditioner. The cost will be quite a bit higher for a unit that can effectively cool 1,450 square feet than one that is just cooling 400 square feet, but the overall savings may be worth it over time. It all depends on the relative efficiency of the units.

Plus mini-splits can also heat the area.

This is a cost versus return question.
If you do not need the central AC running and only need the upstairs bedrooms cooled the Mini-split or even a window AC unit will do the job.
The issue is, how long does it take to recover the cost? We cannot do the math here as we don't have necessary info to input figures, however the formula would be: (Cost of the new AC unit/s including installation as well as possible electrical additions)   divided by (the monthly savings of not running the central AC) = time to recover investment.
That figure will help you determine if it is cost effective in your mind.
You should also consider that adding the mini-splits may add value to the home and be an asset in the future when you look to sell. Depending on your area they could be looked at as ugly and a liability. (from a possible buyers perspective).
The final factor is simple comfort. Is it worth the money spent to make you comfortable to do your job and sleep.
The bottom line is you need to do your research to determine if mini-splits are a good choice for you.

If needing to buy something, for small rooms the minis are quite cheap.  More than a small AC unit but they add in heating also, and provide both for less electric cost
